# How to give priority to filters in "WHERE" condition in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following data

| Id | Indicator_1 | Indicator_2 | Order_Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | L | 123 |
| 2 | X | null | 123 |
| 3 | X | null | null |
| 4 | null | null | null |
| 5 | null | null | 456 |

The logic should be hide if:

1. IF indicator_1 = X AND indicator_2 = L, then hide the record
2. if indicator_1= X and Order_Number  is null, then hide the record

I want to **exclude** rows 1 and 3  from the table

I tried the following query but this doesn't seems to be working

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.Indicator_1,
       a.Indicator_2,
       a.Order_Number,
       a.*
FROM   dummy a
WHERE  ( ( a.indicator_1 <> 'X'AND a.indicator_2 <> 'L' )
          OR 
         ( a.indicator_1 <> 'X'AND a.Order_Number IS NOT NULL ) 

      )
```

Comment: Please include the expected output.

Comment: I want to exclude rows 1 and 3  from the table

Answer (score 0):

Your condition can be simplified to:

```
WHERE NOT (
  COALESCE(indicator_1, ' ') = 'X' 
  AND 
  (COALESCE(indicator_2, ' ') = 'L' OR Order_Number IS NULL)
)
```

or:

```
WHERE 
  COALESCE(indicator_1, ' ') <> 'X' 
  OR 
  NOT (COALESCE(indicator_2, ' ') = 'L' OR Order_Number IS NULL)
```

or:

```
WHERE 
  COALESCE(indicator_1, ' ') <> 'X' 
  OR
  (COALESCE(indicator_2, ' ') <> 'L' AND Order_Number IS NOT NULL)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/POto1HUU).

Comment: Hi @forpas this is blocking the rows where a.indicator_1= X AND a.Order_Number IS NOT NULL  The logic should be hide if:

1. IF indicator_1 = X AND indicator_2 = L, then hide the record
2. if indicator_1= X and POrder_Number  is null, then hide the record

Comment: @SiddharthBhardwaj what do you mean *blocking*? The logic that you described filters out the rows with: `a.indicator_1= X AND a.Order_Number IS NOT NULL`. If this is not what you want then you should clarify.

Comment: PS :  The logic should be hide if:

IF indicator_1 = X AND indicator_2 = L, then hide the record
if indicator_1= X and POrder_Number is null, then hide the record**  @forpas

Comment: I have simplified the description please see